# What happens to specific questions, when new site in this area is created?

Tags: discussion, migration, site-crossover, migrated-questions

What happened to Drupal-tagged questions, when Drupal Answers were created? Were they all migrated to new site or new site is responsible only for accepting *new* questions?

What is current SE politics  about this? If a new site for a new area of expertise is created (comes out of Beta), but this site entirely covers, what was once handled on Stack Exchange, then what happens to the questions, that already exists there?

Comment: Afaik, nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content is not migrated. It remains on the site it is on. The fact that there is a new site with overlapping subject-matter does not make it off-topic on the "old" site either.

And even if there would ever be a migration path to the new site, migrations can only happen within 60 days. So no, old content is never moved.